# Is there any specific icon to use for a 'New Tab' button?

Tags: website-design, icons

I have a button on my web page, this button once clicked will open a new tab and take the user there.

I'm just wondering is there any convention on what icon I should use for this button? At the moment it's a 'url' icon.

[image: Current icon of chain links]

http://coinpolice.com/wp-content/mingle-forum-skins/ElegantPress/images/bbc/url.png

But since I'm opening a new tab, should I use somthing different?

The website is a professional / business site.

Comment: Are you planning to open a new tab to something *within* the same site, or *external* to your site?

Comment: Ah, well the link is configurable from the users end. So the destination is up to them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For links which leave your webpage, I'm fond of this icon: https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/external-link

The shape depicts a box (which could represent either the current window/tab, or the current site) with an arrow leaving its boundaries.

A prime example of this in use is Wikipedia, which uses a similar icon for reference links at the bottom of articles (see [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villgro) which I pulled from the Random Article tool).

---

Per your comment, if the links are configurable, I'm going to guess that often the link will be external, so the icon I discuss above may work well for you.

Another approach to consider is simply using the URL of the `<a>` tag as its label. For example, if you're making a user profile page, instead of showing:

[My Website](http://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/action)

Let users enter their website but show it as:

Website: http://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/action

Comment: I actually found that icon myself not long after I posted this question. Looks perfect. Thanks for the suggestion all the same!

Comment: That icon you're referencing is for external links, not opening a new tab.  That shouldn't be the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

That icon is normally used for adding a link when editing something.

Most browsers have shortcut keys which allow the user to choose to open a link in a new tab. I can't think of a site that indicates to the user that they are opening a tab, they just do it. Gmail, Facebook, etc. all do this when you click something that takes you off their site, and it's up to you to notice that there is an extra tab.

I would say that you probably don't need to worry about showing it as an option, either force it to always happen, or let the user choose via the browser itself.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of. Most browsers (Firefox, Safari, Internet Explorer) seem to use a plus icon (+) to indicate the creation of a new tab.

However, a (+) next to your links is awkward and confusing. A common convention is to use an icon that is focused on the *action*: leaving. Icons like [this one from Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/sign-out/) are a good place to start:

[image]

Or you can always stick with the HTML character: (→).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there's no command to open a new tab - it simply opens a new window and your browser will put that in a tab (so if the user has an old browser, a new window will be opened). I wouldn't worry about making a special icon since there are no standards for this (e.g. the icon will probably be more confused if you try to start a new standard).

If you are concerned, add a small text nearby the link that says that clicking the link will open the site in new window.